# ng-repeat filtered by object of previous ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this structure, but i don't know how can I filter a **ng-repeat** content with an object of previous **ng-repeat** iteration.

//############################################################################//

my **model**:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [angular.filter]);

app.controller('controller', function($scope){

$scope.dashboards =[{"name":"Dashboard 1","category":"C1","subcategory":"SC1"},
                    {"name":"Dashboard 2","category":"C1","subcategory":"SC2"},
                    {"name":"Dashboard 3","category":"C2","subcategory":"SC1"},
                    {"name":"Dashboard 4","category":"C2","subcategory":"SC2"},
                    {"name":"Dashboard 5","category":"C2","subcategory":"SC3"}];
});
```

//############################################################################//

my **html**:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="controller">

<div ng-repeat="dashboard in dashboards | unique: 'category'"><!--Level 1-->
   <h2>{{dashboard.category}}</h2>
   <div ng-repeat="dashboard in dashboards | filter: { category: {{dashboard.category}} } | unique: 'subcategory'"><!--Level 2-->
      </h3>{{dashboard.subcategory}}</h3>
      <div ng-repeat="dashboard in dashboards | filter: { subcategory: {{dashboard.subcategory}} }"><!--Level 3-->
         <p>{{dashboard.name}}</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

My problem is that I do not know how to use the contents of the lower level to filter the ng-repeat.

For example i am trying to filter level 2 with the category of level 1 using an expresion, and filtering level 3 with the subcategory of level 2 using other expresion

*In levels 1 and 2 I use a filter that returns me the unique values ​​of my model

Comment: I think you need to better explain what you are trying to do.   You can certainly use variables from a higher scope but it just isn't clear to me what you want.

Comment: I edit the question for a better explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with the HTML that are fairly straightforward.

Firstly, expressions (`{{ }}`) are not allowed inside an `ng-repeat`;  the parser will figure out the properties without the expression syntax.

```html
<div ng-repeat="dashboard in dashboards | unique: 'category'">
  <!--Level 1-->
  <h2>{{dashboard.category}}</h2>
  <div ng-repeat="dashboard in dashboards | filter: { category: dashboard.category } | unique: 'subcategory'">
    <!--Level 2-->
    <h3>{{dashboard.subcategory}}</h3>
    <div ng-repeat="dashboard in dashboards | filter: { subcategory: dashboard.subcategory }">
      <!--Level 3-->
      <p>{{dashboard.name}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/dniUyHdIWGFOWYJyKjjf?p=preview

This isn't the whole story, however.  The Level 3 `div` needs to be filtered by *both* the `category` and `subcategory`.

```html
<div ng-repeat="dashboard in dashboards | unique: 'category'">
  <!--Level 1-->
  <h2>{{dashboard.category}}</h2>
  <div ng-repeat="dashboard in dashboards | filter: { category: dashboard.category } | unique: 'subcategory'">
    <!--Level 2-->
    <h3>{{dashboard.subcategory}}</h3>
    <div ng-repeat="dashboard in dashboards | filter: { category: dashboard.category, subcategory: dashboard.subcategory }">
      <!--Level 3-->
      <p>{{dashboard.name}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/6ClArqDH3OiQ7ECT95YD?p=preview

Comment: Thank you so much for your help